# Dominated convergence theorem for $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{n^{3/2}x}{1+n^2x^2}\; dx$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I want to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{n^{3/2}x}{1+n^2x^2}\; dx=0$$
using the Lebesgue DCT. Obviously, $\frac{n^{3/2}x}{1+n^2x^2}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and for all $x\in[0,1]$. For the same reason, I can see intuitively that there must be a function that $g(x)\ge \frac{n^{3/2}x}{1+n^2x^2}$ for all $n$, but I can not find such a function. What should I do to define this function $g$. The problem is that I can not define such $g$ that dominates all functions that are inside the integral Any hint will be very appreciated.

Comment: $u=nx$ gives $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int^n_0\frac{u}{1+u^2}\,du$

Comment: I don't think you can really solve this problem with DCT in the way you intended to do it. The "fatal" flaw is that $f_n(x):=\frac{n^{3/2}x}{1+n^2x^2}$ has a maximum in $x=1/n$ as you can easily check by differentiating, and $f_n(1/n)=\sqrt{n}/2$. Thus the $f_n$'s are not uniformly limited above by such a function $g$.

Comment: @FedericoClerici That was my first thought, but the extra half in the exponent gets in the way.

Comment: @FedericoClerici There may be an intergable function $g$ with $g(\frac 1 n) =\sqrt n /2$ for all $n$.  Your arguement does not prove that DCT cannot be applied.

Comment: Well, I didn't say that it can't be applied at all, I said that it can't be used In the way meant by the OP since there does not exist a function $g$ satisfying $f_n(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x\in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$u=nx$ gives $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int^n_0\frac{u}{1+u^2}\,du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\log(1+n^2)$